# Create vertical layers in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

For each level of the y-axis I want to separate the lines vertically by a small distance so they aren't overlapping. Can someone help me achieve this please? Also, I don't want it to be random by a method such as jittering. The placement needs to be constant across all levels.

```
data(mtcars)
str(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl = as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
mtcars$carb = as.factor(mtcars$carb)
ggplot(mtcars) + aes(mpg,cyl,color = carb) + geom_line() + 
   geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `position_dodge`, though because that only has an option to set `width`, I believe that you will have to construct it with the opposite axes, then use `coord_flip` to get it back the way you wanted it:

```
ggplot(mtcars
       , aes(cyl, mpg
             ,color = carb) ) +
  geom_line(position = position_dodge(0.3)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  coord_flip()
```

Gives:

[image]